# Convert php linux time of 2 months ago to an equivalent MySQL time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this PHP code

```
$date = date('Y-m-01', strtotime("-2 months", time()));
$query = "call getPeople('$date');";
```

What is the command to get the same day as `date('Y-m-01', strtotime("-2 months", time()));` in MySQL?

Comment: You can also use FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) in your sql query, so you can just send it a timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)
```

OR

```
 SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

if you need to get first date of that month.

```
(date_add(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH), INTERVAL(1-DAYOFMonth(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))) day)) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
$query = "call getPeople( DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of redundant to be converting it to date in PHP and then back.

You can do this ..

```
$ts = time();
$query = 'call getPeople(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME('.$ts.'), INTERVAL -2 MONTH))';
```

or even easier

```
$query = 'call getPeople(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH))';
```